# Google Calendar query not returning events within date range

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

This Google calendar query should return events only between 1/1/2011 and 2/20/2011 but instead it returns events from 4/27/2009 to 3/27/2011

> http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?singleevents=true&sortorder=ascending&start-min=2011-01-01T00:00:00&start-max=2011-02-20T23:59:59

What am I missing?

**EDIT**
In case anyone else was puzzled like me, I was viewing the result sets in Firefox and the XML parser shows the updated date and not the event dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your exact query in the [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/), it works perfectly.  I get 30 results (after paging through a few pages) and all are between January 1 2011 and February 20 2011.

Also, please use **https**.

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?singleevents=true&sortorder=ascending&start-min=2011-01-01T00:00:00&start-max=2011-02-20T23:59:59
```

Comment: Huh, I ran my query from a browser, should it make a difference? Do you get the same results from a browser? Also technically, https shouldn't make a difference. I'll try the playground later.

Comment: Yes, I just ran the query in my browser, and got the exact same correct results.

Comment: https makes a huge difference from an application perspective.  One of the advantages (there are many) in this case is preventing someone from performing a man-in-the-middle attack on your application and providing it with tainted data.

Comment: You are correct, talk about user operator error, I was viewing the result sets in Firefox and the XML parser shows the `updated` date and not the event dates. https is not a big deal in my case since it's a public calendar after all.